# Can I change a Laravel error message globally?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-validation

I can do stuff like this in the request.

```
public function messages() 
{
    return [
        'title.required' => 'A title is required',
        'body.required'  => 'A message is required',
    ];
}
```

But I still feel like I will repeat a lot of my code, cause in my case, I will also repeat many of the same error messages for different errors and fields. So is there a way to modify the `required` error, for example, for the scope of the whole project?

Comment: Are you looking for this? https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#custom-messages-for-specific-attributes